# Wordpress update_user_meta onclick button with Ajax

Tags: javascript, database, user-meta

I have a button that is limited to 7 clicks, when clicking number 5 is disabled, My problem if the user login from different device, the count start againg in 0 same as refresh page.
my needs is, Save in user_meta the click number result and update if click again until click number 5 the button change to disabled.

In DB user_meta info:
user_id: user_id
meta_key:clickCounterTrav
meta_value: 1 (number of clicks)

> Here is the code when page load, disable button if number of click is > 4 **Do Not Work**:

```
<script>
    window.addEventListener("load", ()=>{
   if(clickCounterTrav>4)
        document.getElementById("btnTraPack").disabled = true;
    if(clickCounterTrav>4)
        document.getElementById('btnTraPack').style.pointerEvents = 'none';
    if(clickCounterTrav>4)
        document.getElementById('btnTraPack').style.color = "#54595F";
    if(clickCounterTrav>4)
        document.getElementById('btnTraPack').style.borderColor = "#54595F";
    if(clickCounterTrav>4)
        document.getElementById("showResultsTra").style.visibility = "visible";
});
```

> **Here is the rest of code:**

```
var clickCounterTrav = 0;

function CounterTrav() {
  clickCounterTrav += 1;
  document.getElementById("clickCounterTrav").innerHTML = clickCounterTrav + " Travel Pack you have Shared!";
  
    if(clickCounterTrav>4)
        document.getElementById('btnTraPack').style.pointerEvents = 'none';
    if(clickCounterTrav>4)
        document.getElementById('btnTraPack').style.color = "#54595F";
    if(clickCounterTrav>4)
        document.getElementById('btnTraPack').style.borderColor = "#54595F";
    if(clickCounterTrav>4)
    document.getElementById("resultTraveler").innerHTML = clickCounterTrav + " Travel Pack Shared.<br>Your Stock is Over!";
  if(clickCounterTrav>4)
  document.getElementById("showResultsTra").style.visibility = "visible";

console.log(clickCounterTrav); // 111
var CounterTrav_value = jQuery(this).attr('clickCounterTrav');
jQuery.ajax({
    url: '/wp-admin/admin-ajax.php',
        
        data : {
            action : 'CounterTrav_update', 
            CounterTrav_value : CounterTrav_value,
        },
        beforeSend: function() {
               console.log('Updating Field');
        },
        success : function( response ) {
             console.log('Success');
        },
        
    });
}
</script>
```

**console log**

```
1
Updating Field
Success
```

But in DB user_meta **Did Not Update Any**

**functions.php**

```
add_action( 'wp_ajax_CounterTrav_update', 'CounterTrav_update' );
add_action( 'wp_ajax_nopriv_CounterTrav_update', 'CounterTrav_update' ); // This lines it's because we are using AJAX on the FrontEnd.

function CounterTrav_update(){
    if(empty($_REQUEST) || !isset($_REQUEST)) {
        ajaxStatus('error', 'Nothing to update.');
    } else {
        try {
            $user = wp_get_current_user();
            $CounterTrav_value = $_POST['clickCounterTrav'];
            if ($CounterTrav_value == 'clickCounterTrav') {
                update_user_meta( $user->ID, 'clickCounterTrav', $_POST['clickCounterTrav'] );
            }
            die();
        } catch (Exception $e){
            echo 'Caught exception: ',  $e->getMessage(), "\n";
        }
    }
}
```

Please Can you Help Me?

Comment: Have you checked the error log on the browser console also on the back-end side?

Comment: @RajneeshTiwari, Yes, but no error in console and same in error_log, none erros, It's super weird... Any Help my Friend?

Comment: Also this in network displaying
wp-admin/admin-ajax.php?_tutor_nonce=0978f464eb&action=CounterTrav_update&CounterTrav_value=1
Request Method: GET
Status Code: 200

Comment: do one thing in CounterTrav_update() just do the echo "xyz", and check if you getting an "xyz" as a response in the browser's console. If still, it is not working. Just share your HTML code and I will give it a try.

Comment: sorry i don't know how i missed this,
you ajax is of "GET" type so kindly, in PHP update $_POST['clickCounterTrav'] to $_GET['CounterTrav_value']. Let me know. this should work. I just tested this on my system. as well as remove this if ($CounterTrav_value == 'clickCounterTrav'), you don;t need this

Comment: My FRIEND!!!! Now in part is Working!!!!, i follow your recomendations, and finaly is like this  $user = wp_get_current_user();
$CounterTrav_value = $_GET['CounterTrav_value']; update_user_meta( $user->ID, 'clickCounterTrav', $CounterTrav_value );   die(); } catch (Exception $e){ echo 'Caught exception: ',  $e->getMessage(), "\n";}  But now i have a secund issue, if i click two  times the button, then update user_meta with 2 value, and if user came back and click one's again, (click 1 in this session) then update the user_meta with value 1, has to be 3 right?, I appreciate any help again

Comment: @RajneeshTiwari, Thank you for your help, i found out how make it work, now i can save in user_meta perfect. I will answer my question to show you the final code. But i still need your help. have in the code a litle issue. Hope you can help me up!

Answer (score 1):

Here is my oun answer, hope some can someone help with this.
I add a comments in code

```
<script>
//Now this windows.addEventListener, don't Work at All. I need some like
this, when the user came back in other session or reload the page,
The button, **still disabled** But i don't know how to make it work.
PLEASE ANY HELP? 

     window.addEventListener('load', ()=>{
       
    if(resultTraveler2>6)
    document.getElementById('btnTraPack').innerHTML = "Your Stock is Over!";
     if(resultTraveler2>6)
        document.getElementById('btnTraPack').disabled = true;
    if(resultTraveler2>6)
        document.getElementById('btnTraPack').style.pointerEvents = 'none';
    if(resultTraveler2>6)
        document.getElementById('btnTraPack').style.color = "#54595F";
    if(resultTraveler2>6)
        document.getElementById('btnTraPack').style.borderColor = "#54595F";
    if(resultTraveler2>6)
        document.getElementById('showResultsTra').style.visibility = "visible";
});

//From here, all work as i need, OK!
 
var clickCounterTrav = 0
function CounterTrav() {
    
  clickCounterTrav += 1;
  document.getElementById("resultTraveler1").innerHTML = clickCounterTrav;
}
var btnTraPackClick = document.querySelector(".btnTraPack");
var clicksContainer = document.querySelector(".clicksContainer");
var totalEl = document.createElement("span");
clicksContainer.appendChild(totalEl);

btnTraPackClick.addEventListener("click", function(e) {
  if (!e.target.classList.contains("clicksContainer")) {
    
    var ClickSum = document.querySelectorAll(".resultTraveler1, .resultTraveler2");
    let total = (0);
    ClickSum.forEach(item => {
      total += parseInt(item.innerText, 10)
   })
   totalEl.innerHTML = total;
    
  }

    if(totalEl.innerHTML>6)
        document.getElementById('btnTraPack').style.pointerEvents = 'none';
    if(totalEl.innerHTML>6)
        document.getElementById('btnTraPack').style.color = "#54595F";
    if(totalEl.innerHTML>6)
        document.getElementById('btnTraPack').style.borderColor = "#54595F";
    if(totalEl.innerHTML>6)
    document.getElementById('btnTraPack').innerHTML = "Your Stock is Over!";
  if(totalEl.innerHTML>6)
  document.getElementById('showResultsTra').style.visibility = "visible";
 
var CounterTrav_value = totalEl.innerHTML;
console.log(clickCounterTrav); // 111

jQuery.ajax({
    url: '/wp-admin/admin-ajax.php',
        
        data : {
            action : 'CounterTrav_update', 
            CounterTrav_value : CounterTrav_value,
        },
        beforeSend: function() {
               console.log('Updating Field');
        },
        success : function( response ) {
             console.log('Success');
        },
   })    
});
</script>
```

I Appreciate Any Help. Thanks!!!

Comment: Thanks For any help @RajneeshTiwari, I Found out how fix my issue, and now is Working like a charm !
My case is close.

Comment: Ok nice to hear that. sorry i was busy from last few days and didn't check your notification, but it's good now you have solved this